# xslt transformation returning blank values

Tags: xslt, xpath

I am just getting into xslt transformation and after going through a tutorial I tried doing some code in visual studio 2008. I tried the following code after linking the xml document I needed as input:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:template match="/">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:element name="entry">
     <xsl:attribute name="published" >
      <xsl:value-of select="entry/published"/>
    </xsl:attribute>
    <xsl:attribute name="title" >
      <xsl:value-of select="title"/>
    </xsl:attribute>
    <xsl:attribute name="summary" >
      <xsl:value-of select="summary"/>
    </xsl:attribute>
     </xsl:element>
   </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>
```

here is a sample of the xml file:

```
<entry xmlns:gnip="http://www.p.com/schemas/2010" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom">
<id>tag:search,2005:38587000730689536</id>
<published>2011-02-18T13:13:52Z</published>
<updated>2011-02-18T13:13:52Z</updated>
<title>nachopego (J Ignacio Pe&#xF1;a G.) posted a note</title>
<summary type="html">Truculencia: en Nayarit no nada mas
     el engrudo se hace  bolas</summary>
<category term="StatusPosted" label="Status Posted"/>
 <category term="NotePosted" label="Note Posted"/>
 <link rel="alternate" 
       type="text/html"  href="http://nachopego/statuses/38587000730689536"/>
```

Comment: Good question, +1. See my answer for a complete solution and explanation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**This is the Most FAQ in the xpath and xslt tags**: XPath expressions against an XML document with a default namespace.

Just search for "xpath default namespace" and you will find many good answers.

**Solution**:

1. **Add a namespace declaration in the XSLT stylesheet for the default namespace** of the XML document. Use the prefix (say) "x:" in this declaration.
2. **In any XPath expression that references an element by name, prefix every name with the "x:"** prefix.

**Your code becomes**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
 xmlns:x="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom" >
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:element name="entry">
                <xsl:attribute name="published" >
                    <xsl:value-of select="x:entry/x:published"/>
                </xsl:attribute>
                <xsl:attribute name="title" >
                    <xsl:value-of select="x:title"/>
                </xsl:attribute>
                <xsl:attribute name="summary" >
                    <xsl:value-of select="x:summary"/>
                </xsl:attribute>
            </xsl:element>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**and now it produces some output.**

**Explanation**:

Xpath always treats unprefixed names as belonging to "no namespace". Thus if an expression contains the name `someName`, XPath tries to find an element with the name `someName` that belongs to "no namespace" and fails, because all the elements in the document belong to its non-empty default namespace.

**The solution** (as the one above) **is** to refer to the names using a *prefixed name*, where the prefix is bound exactly to the default namespace of the XML document.

Answer (score 1):

By the way, this code

```
     <xsl:element name="entry">
        <xsl:attribute name="published" >
            <xsl:value-of select="x:entry/x:published"/>
        </xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:attribute name="title" >
            <xsl:value-of select="x:title"/>
        </xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:attribute name="summary" >
            <xsl:value-of select="x:summary"/>
        </xsl:attribute>
    </xsl:element>
```

can be written much more legibly as

```
<entry published="{x:entry/x:published}" 
       title="{x:title}" 
       summary="{x:summary}"/>
```